# NodeJS Axios response undefined on console.log API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, http-get

I try to make this code work.

```
const axios = require('axios');
let bodyapi = axios.get('there's my api')
console.log(bodyapi.data) <- undefined
let body = bodyapi.data
console.log(body.discord) <- couldn't get parameter ''discord'' of undefined
```

Response type of the API:

```
"discord":{"Category":"activation","Qty":1542,"Price":1}
"vkontakte":{"Category":"activation","Qty":133,"Price":21}
```

I get it ''undefined''. Running on NodeJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

axios return promise

```
const axios = require('axios');

// use async await 
(async ()=>{
let bodyapi = await axios.get('there's my api')
console.log(bodyapi.data) // response
})()

// other way
axios.get('there's my api').then(data=> console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain a then method as axios returns promise.
you can also chain a catch method to catch potential errors.

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('there's my api').then(bodyapi => {
console.log(bodyapi.data) 
let body = bodyapi.data
console.log(body.discord)
}).catch(error => {
console.log(error);
});
```

hope this helps. GOOD LUCK :)

Answer (score 0):

Axios Returns a promise. You can look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/axios/axios)

You can either use await to wait for the response in that case you should use a try catch block to make sure you take care of the errors from your discord Endpoint. This is a good read on error handling for asnyc/wait ([here](https://itnext.io/error-handling-with-async-await-in-js-26c3f20bc06a))
Like @arshpreet suggested

```
(async ()=>{
try{

  let bodyapi = await axios.get('there's my api')
   console.log(bodyapi.data) // response
  } catch(error){
     console.error(error)
  }
})()
```

Or you can do it then and catch to take care of the errors. 
 just like waleed has mentioned.